# SQL query with specific week days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I have a requirement to check records from Sunday 7 p.m. to Friday 5 a.m. between May 2021 to August 2021. How should I write it in the where condition?

Below query is for the 3 months but I want it from Sunday 7 p.m. to Friday 5 a.m.

```
l1.[PickupTime] between '2021/05/01 19:00:00' and '2021/09/01 05:00:00'
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: 1. Please confirm what datatype `PickupTime` is 2. I recommend ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd) when using date literals.

Comment: So what isn't working about it? We need a [mre] with sample data, your attempt, the results you are getting and the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you want:

```
where l1.[PickupTime] between '2021-05-01' and '2021-09-02' and
      ((datename(weekday, l1.[PickupTime]) = 'Sunday' and 
        time(l1.[PickupTime]) >= '19:00:00'
       ) or
       (datename(weekday, l1.[PickupTime]) in ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday') or
       (datename(weekday, l1.[PickupTime]) = 'Friday' and
        time(l1.[PickupTime]) < '05:00:00'
       )
      )
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. It is working correctly.